# Как в JS реализовать в калькуляторе функцию вызова сообщения при делении на ноль

Tags: javascript

```
<form name="frm">
            <table border="1">
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="5" id="res"><input name="ReadOut" type="Text"><br /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td><button type="button" name="7" value="7" onClick="NumPressed(7)">7</button></td>
                  <td><button type="button" name="8" value="8" onClick="NumPressed(8)">8</button></td>
                  <td><button type="button" name="9" value="9" onClick="NumPressed(9)">9</button></td>
                  <td><button type="button" name="/" value=" / " onclick="Operation('/')">/</button></td>
                  <td><button type="button" name="c" value="C" onclick="Clear()">C</button></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td><button type="button" name="4" value="4" onClick="NumPressed(4)">4</button></td>
                  <td><button type="button" name="5" value="5" onClick="NumPressed(5)">5</button></td>
                  <td><button type="button" name="6" value="6" onClick="NumPressed(6)">6</button></td>
                  <td><button type="button" name="*" value="*" onclick="Operation('*')">*</button></td>
                  <td><button type="button" name="pm" onclick="Neg()">&plusmn;</button></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td><button type="button" name="1" value="1" onClick="NumPressed(1)">1</button></td>
                  <td><button type="button" name="2" value="2" onClick="NumPressed(2)">2</button></td>
                  <td><button type="button" name="3" value="3" onClick="NumPressed(3)">3</button></td>
                  <td><button type="button" name="-" value="-" onclick="Operation('-')">-</button></td>
                  <td rowspan="2"> <button type="button" id="f" name="=" value="=" onclick="Operation('=')">=</button><br /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="2"><button type="button" name="0" value="0" onClick="NumPressed(0)">0</button></td>
                  <td><button type="button" name="." value="." onclick="Decimal()">.</button></td>
                  <td><button type="button" name="+" value="+" onclick="Operation('+')">+</button></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </form>
<script>
      var Fcalc = document.frm;
var Currents = 0;
var FlagNewNum = false;
var PendingOp = "";
        function NumPressed (Num) 
{
        if (FlagNewNum) 
        {
            Fcalc.ReadOut.value = Num;
            FlagNewNum = false;
        }   
        else 
        {
            if (Fcalc.ReadOut.value == "0")
                Fcalc.ReadOut.value = Num;
            else
                Fcalc.ReadOut.value += Num;
        }
}
function Operation (Op) 
{
        var Readout = Fcalc.ReadOut.value;
        if (FlagNewNum && PendingOp != "=")
        {
            Fcalc.ReadOut.value = Currents;
        }
        else
        {
            FlagNewNum = true;
            if ( '+' == PendingOp )
                Currents += parseFloat(Readout);
            else if ( '-' == PendingOp )
                Currents -= parseFloat(Readout);
            else if ( '/' == PendingOp )
                Currents /= parseFloat(Readout);

            else if ( '*' == PendingOp )
                Currents *= parseFloat(Readout);

            else
                Currents = parseFloat(Readout);
            Fcalc.ReadOut.value = Currents;
            PendingOp = Op;
        }
}
function Decimal () 
{
        var curReadOut = Fcalc.ReadOut.value;
        if (FlagNewNum) 
        {
            curReadOut = "0.";
            FlagNewNum = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (curReadOut.indexOf(".") == -1)
                curReadOut += ".";
        }
        Fcalc.ReadOut.value = curReadOut;
}
    function Clear () 
{
        Currents = 0;
        PendingOp = "";
        Fcalc.ReadOut.value = "0";
        FlagNewNum = true;

 }
 function Neg () 
{
        Fcalc.ReadOut.value = 
        parseFloat(Fcalc.ReadOut.value) * -1;
}
      </script>
```

Comment: Точнее выводилось в окно ввода. Например "Error"

Comment: В текущем виде - никак. Так как деление на 0 - это не ошибка. В принципе можно проверить значение результата и если он равен `Infinity` - То писать ошибку например

Comment: что именно было добавлено в последнем редактировании? и как это относится к сути вопроса?

Comment: Другой вариант калькулятора. Вопрос тот же

Comment: а откуда вы эти скрипты берете?

Comment: Какой у вас странный JS

Comment: @ThisMan, почему странный?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для вашего кода уже предложили ответ

```
function calculate() {
      var eval1 = eval(document.frm.result.value);
      if(Math.abs(eval1) == Infinity) alert('Деление на ноль!');
      else document.frm.result.value = eval1;
}
```

Но это слишком просто и не интересно, да и к тому же лишняя операция выполняется, лучше проверять перед выполнением великого `eval`, давайте подумаем, что мы можем сделать

```
function calculate() {
      var mathString = document.frm.result.value;
      var regexp = new RegExp(/\d*\/0/); // строка вида число/0
      var isZeroDivision= regexp.test(mathString);
      if(isZeroDivision) return alert("Деление на ноль");

      /** ваш код из ф-ции calculate */
}
```

Еще более извращенный вариант, в вашем стиле

```
function calculate() {
      var mathString = document.frm.result.value;
      var len = mathString.len;
      var lastNumber = mathString[len-1]; // последние элемент
      if(lastNumber == '0') {
          /* если последняя цифра 0, уже стоит задуматься, 
             а не пытаемся ли мы на него поделить
          */
          if(mathString[len-2] == '/') return alert("Деление на ноль");
      }

      /** ваш код из ф-ции calculate */
}
```

**З.Ы.**
Вообще, так калькуляторы писать не стоит, а `eval` вообще бяка

Comment: а еще, код в вопросе поменялся

Comment: @Grundy, Господи, неужели я так долго ответ писал?:D

Comment: там с редактированием небольшие непонятки были, автор поменял код, потом приняли правку к старому коду, а потом откатили :)

Comment: Спасибо!Заработало!

Answer (score 1):

не стоит задавать функции через `onclick=""`

Для этого изобрели `e.addEventListener();`